# How to get plots in several pdf pages using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need help to process graphs into multiple pdf pages. Here is my current code:

```
file <- read.csv(file="file.csv") 
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(plyr)

gg1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x=TIME, y=var1, colour = "z1"), file) +
  geom_line(aes(x=TIME, y=var2, colour = "z2"), file) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=TIME, y=var3), file) + facet_wrap( ~ ID, ncol=5)+ 
  xlab("x") +
  ylab("Y") +
  ggtitle(" x ") + scale_colour_manual(name="Legend",
    values=c(z1="red", z2 ="blue")) + theme(legend.position="bottom")   
gg10 = do.call(marrangeGrob, c(gg1, list(nrow=4, ncol=4)))
ggsave("need10.pdf", gg10)
```

Here is the image created, without splitting my images

[image]

I wish to have a code to get my plots in a 4 by 4 layout in multiple pages. The last two lines of my code need adjustment and I do not know how to fix it myself.

Comment: This seems useful: [A set of additional functions for ggplot2](https://github.com/guiastrennec/ggplus). I googled `facet_wrap multiple pages`.

Comment: i substituted                                                                                                                                                                                                                           `multi.plot <- marrangeGrob(grobs = gg1, nrow = 2, ncol = 2, top = quote(paste(gg1$labels$title,'\nPage', g, 'of', pages)))
pdf('Example_marrangeGrob.pdf', w = 12, h = 8)
 print(multi.plot)
dev.off()  ` but received the error _Error in gList(data = list(wrapvp = list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"_. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `ggplus` wrapper appears to do what you want. I changed a couple of things in the code block below from your original: `facet_wrap` is commented out, and `file` is moved to `ggplot` so that it doesn't have to be re-specified in each `geom_*`:

```
gg1 <- ggplot(file) +
  geom_line(aes(x=TIME, y=var1, colour = "z1")) +
  geom_line(aes(x=TIME, y=var2, colour = "z2")) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=TIME, y=var3)) +
  # facet_wrap( ~ ID, ncol=5) +
  xlab("x") +
  ylab("Y") +
  ggtitle(" x ") + 
  scale_colour_manual(name="Legend",
    values=c(z1="red", z2 ="blue"),
    labels=c("X","Y")) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")   

devtools::install_github("guiastrennec/ggplus")
library(ggplus)
pdf("need10.pdf")
gg10 <- facet_multiple(plot=gg1, facets="ID", ncol = 4, nrow = 4)
dev.off()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you soooooo much!!! This is amazing! it saved me probably another ~4 hours of looking around.

Comment: the last page doesnt print the plot

Comment: @Weihuang Wong

I will highly appreciate if you could help me with this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45475249/ggplusplots-on-multiple-pages

Answer (score 1):

**4 years later...**

since `ggplus` is [deprecated](https://github.com/guiastrennec/ggplus#warning), you might consider using [`ggforce`](https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/index.html). You could use any of the relevant [`facet_*`](https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/index.html#section-facets) options as described in the documentation. E.g., `facet_matrix`:

```
# Standard use:
ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_point(aes(x = .panel_x, y = .panel_y)) +
  facet_matrix(vars(displ, cty, hwy))
```

[image]