# Putting multiple ggplots into one PDF with different scales

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, ggsave

I'd like to put several plots into one PDF, with a new page for each plot. Each plot is generated with ggplot, and each needs a different scale.

I know how to output individual plots into individual PDFs at the appropriate scale, like so:

```
plot1 <-
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point()
ggsave(file="plot1.pdf", plot=plot1, scale=3)

plot2 <-
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=hp)) +
  geom_point()
ggsave(file="plot2.pdf", plot=plot2, scale=1)
```

I also know how to put multiple plots into one PDF, with each plot on a separate page, like so:

```
# Open PDF to save all plots to
pdf(file="plots.pdf")

# Print plots to the pdf
print(plot1)
print(plot2)

# Turn off PDF plotting
dev.off()
```

However, what I can't work out is how to give each individual plot within the PDF a different scale?

Comment: Yes, none seem to be able to change the scale of individual plots. egs coming ...

Comment: Sorry, was meant to be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234248/printing-multiple-ggplots-into-a-single-pdf-multiple-plots-per-page

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Rekyt/a7846af7c4c5fb5a48ea

Comment: https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-save-a-ggplot/#save-ggplot-into-a-pdf-file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858830/how-to-get-plots-in-several-pdf-pages-using-ggplot2/38859493