Using a for loop to plot each column of a data frame?
I have a data frame that consists of a Wavenumber column and 48 other columns for Intensity. Is there a way to use a for loop to plot each Intensity column with the Wavelength column, so I'd end up with 48 separate plots?
Furthermore, is there a way to put all of these plots in a PDF file?
I have tried using
for (i in df){
  plot(Wavenumber, i)
}

This gives me the correct plot, but I would rather use ggplot2 because of all the customization. When I try with ggplot2 though, no graphs pop up.

Inside a for loop you have to explicitly call print(), see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678261/ggplot-does-not-work-if-it-is-inside-a-for-loop-although-it-works-outside-of-it. For exporting to pdf have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034177/save-multiple-ggplots-using-a-for-loop or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234248/printing-multiple-ggplots-into-a-single-pdf-multiple-plots-per-page or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74725648/is-there-a-way-to-save-multiple-ggplots-to-a-single-pdf-while-using-a-for-loop

… and, since ggplot2 likes tidy data, you’d be better off pivoting your data frame to long format.
